# vb.net webchat client works fine locally does not work on windows server thinking threading to tcpclient?

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, signalr, tcpclient

I am not sure if it is signalR.i believe signalR is working exactly as it needs
I am thinking it has to do with the threading to my tcpclient
as said this runs fine locally through IIS on my PC both through visual studio and also through regular IIS 
deploying on an actual windows server hosting  it stops right around the time it should open a thread to my tcpclient class - 
index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="wc2.css">
    <script src="scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>
     <!-- this cssfile can be found in the jScrollPane package -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.jscrollpane.css" />
  <!-- the jScrollPane script -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var connection = $.hubConnection();
        var hub = connection.createHubProxy("hitCount");
        connection.logging = true;

       // $.hubConnection().start();
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000) + 10000;
        var Nick = prompt("what is your nickname", "webchat" + num);
        var DefaultChannel = "%#the\\blobby";
        var mychannel = "";
        var myNick = "";
        var mygate = "";
        var channelWindowCreated = 0;
        var isChan_Registered = false;
        var ChanModes_set = "";
        var isAway = false;
        var entityMap = {
            "&": "&amp;",
            "<": "&lt;",
            ">": "&gt;",
            '"': '&quot;',
            "'": '&#39;',
            "/": '&#x2F;'
        };



function createChannelWindow(chanWin) {
if (channelWindowCreated == 0) {
    var fixChanName = chanWin.replace("%#","").replace("\\b"," ");

 $('<div id="lar" class="MainFrame"><div id="leftside" class="chatWindow"></div><div id="rightside"><div id="rBox.'+chanWin+'" class="rightBox"><div id="iBox.'+chanWin+'" class="infoBox"> \
 <div id="ChannelText">'+fixChanName+'</div><div id="MemberCount"></div></div><div id="uBox.'+chanWin+'" class="userBox"> \
 <p id="dUserNickname"/></div> \
 <div id="lBox.'+chanWin+'" class="listBox" oncontextmenu="return false;""><ol id="selectable"></ol></div></div></div></div> \
    <div id="bottomside-left"><div class="InputPane"> \
    <input id="iInput" type="textbox" class="chatInput" /> \
    <input id="iSend" type="submit" class="SendButton" value="Send" /> \
    <input type="submit" id="iAction" class="ActionButton" value="!" /> \
    </div></div><div id="bottomside-right"><input id="whisperbtn" type="button" /><input id="ignorebtn" type="button" /><input id="checkbtn" type="button" /><input id="profilebtn" type="button" /></div>').appendTo( '#ChannelContainer' );
  channelWindowCreated = 1;
    }
}

function handle_raws(rawstring) {
 var parsed = rawstring.split(" ");
    if (parsed[0] == "AUTH") { 
        var edited_string = rawstring.split(' ').slice(3,4).join(' ');
        edited_string = edited_string.replace(":","");
       //$('#leftside').append('<div class="ServerNode">' + edited_string  + '<br></div>');
   }
   else if (parsed[0] == "PING") { } 
  else if (parsed[1] == "PRIVMSG") {

  } 
  else if (parsed[1] == "MODE") {
   if (parsed[4] != '') {
   }
  }
   else if (parsed[1] == "800") {
     //  $('#leftside').append('<div class="ServerNode">' + rawstring.split(' ').slice(2,8).join(' ')  + '<br></div>');
   }
   else if ((parsed[1] == "001") || (parsed[1] == "002") || (parsed[1] == "003") || (parsed[1] == "004") || (parsed[1] == "251") || (parsed[1] == "252" ) || (parsed[1] == "254") || (parsed[1] == "255") || (parsed[1] == "265") || (parsed[1] == "266") || (parsed[1] == "422"))  {
  edited_string = rawstring.split(' ').slice(3).join(' ');
   edited_string = edited_string.replace(":","");

         // $('#leftside').append('<div class="ServerNode">' + edited_string  + '<br></div>');
   }
    else if ((parsed[1] == "353") || (parsed[1] == "366") || (parsed[1] == "332") || (parsed[1] == "324") || (parsed[1] == "JOIN") || (parsed[1] == "QUIT"))   {

    }
   else {
    //   $('#leftside').append('<div class="ServerNode">' + rawstring  + '<br></div>');
   }

}
function escapeHtml(string) {
            return String(string).replace(/[&<>"'\/]/g, function (s) {
                return entityMap[s];
            });
}
hub.on("onGetNick", function () {
    if (myNick == "") {
        if (Nick == null) {
            Nick = "null" + num;
        }
    }
    else {
        Nick = myNick.replace("Guest_", "");
    }

});
hub.on("onrecordFixChanName", function (hitCount) {
    hitCount = hitCount.replace("%#", "").replace("\\b", " ");
    $('#ChannelText').text(hitCount);
    $('#ChannelText').addClass("registered_room");
});
hub.on("onStatusUpdate", function (hitCount) {
    handle_raws(hitCount);

    // $('#leftside').append('<div class="ServerNode">' + hitCount + '<br></div>');
    $("#leftside").prop({ scrollTop: $("#leftside").prop("scrollHeight") });
});

hub.on("onChannelUpdate", function (hitCount) {
    $('#leftside').append('<div class="ChanNode">' + hitCount + '<br></div>');
    $("#leftside").prop({ scrollTop: $("#leftside").prop("scrollHeight") });
});
hub.on("onrecordGate", function (hitCount) {
    $('#Gate').text(hitCount);
    mygate = hitCount;
});
hub.on("onrecordsetnick", function (setnick) {
    $('#setNick').text(setnick);
    myNick = setnick;

});
hub.on("onnicklistupdate", function (updatednicklist, nickAmount, nickStatus) {
    $('#selectable').html(updatednicklist);
    $('#dUserNickname').removeClass();
    $('#dUserNickname').addClass(nickStatus);
    $('#MemberCount').html(nickAmount + " people chatting");
});
hub.on("onrecordTopicChange", function (topic) {
    $('#topic').text(topic);
});
hub.on("onJoinedChannel", function (channel) {
    createChannelWindow(channel);
    $('#dUserNickname').html('<button id="awaybtn"/>' + myNick);
    mychannel = channel;
    //  $('#rightBox').toggle();

});
hub.on("onRecordHit", function (hitCount) {
    $('#hitCountValue').text(hitCount);
});

hub.on("onOpenChatWindow", function () {

});
hub.on("onJoinMessage", function (nickname, message_recieved) {
    $('#leftside').append('<div class="JoinNode">' + escapeHtml(message_recieved) + '</div>');
    $('#leftside').prop({ scrollTop: $("#leftside").prop("scrollHeight") });

});
hub.on("onChannelMessage", function (nickname, message_recieved) {
    $('#leftside').append('<div class="textNode"><span class="nicktext">' + nickname + '</span> : ' + escapeHtml(message_recieved) + '</div>');
    $('#leftside').prop({ scrollTop: $("#leftside").prop("scrollHeight") });

});

connection.start().done(function () {
    console.log("!!");
    hub.invoke('setNick', Nick, DefaultChannel);
   // hub.invoke('recordHit');
   // createChannelWindow(DefaultChannel);


    $('#ChannelContainer').on('keydown', '.chatInput', function (event) {
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if (keycode == '13') {
            if ($('#iInput').val() != "") {
                message_sent = $('#iInput').val();
                hub.invoke('sendmsg', mychannel, message_sent);
                $('#iInput').val("");
                $('#leftside').append('<div class="textNode"><strong>' + myNick + '</strong> : ' + escapeHtml(message_sent) + '</div>');
                $("#leftside").prop({ scrollTop: $("#lar").prop("scrollHeight") });
            }
        }
    });
    $('#iSend').click(function () {
        if ($('#iInput').val() != "") {
            message_sent = $('#iInput').val();
            hub.invoke('sendmsg', mychannel, message_sent);
            $('#iInput').val("");
            $('#leftside').append('<div class="textNode"><strong>' + myNick + '</strong> : ' + escapeHtml(message_sent) + '</div>');
            $("#leftside").prop({ scrollTop: $("#lar").prop("scrollHeight") });
        }
    });
    $('#iAction').click(function () {
        if ($('#iInput').val() != "") {
            message_sent = $('#iInput').val();
            hub.invoke('sendmsg', mychannel, "ACTION " + message_sent + "");
            $('#iInput').val("");
            $('#leftside').append('<div class="textNode ACTION">' + myNick + ' ' + escapeHtml(message_sent) + '</div>');
            $("#leftside").prop({ scrollTop: $("#lar").prop("scrollHeight") });
        }
    });
    $('#awaybtn').click(function () {
        if (isAway == false) {
            hub.invoke('sendAway', mychannel, "AWAY");
            isAway = true;

            $('#awaybtn').addClass("active");
        }
        else {
            isAway = false;
            hub.invoke('sendAway', mychannel, "");
            $('#awaybtn').removeClass("active");

        }
    });


});
connection.disconnected(function () {
    $('#selectable').html("");
    $('#leftside').append("<span style='cursor:alias;color: green'>disconnected attempting reconnect...</span><br>");

    setTimeout(function () {
        connection.start();
    }, 5000);
});


    </script>

    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#selectable").bind("mousedown", function (e) {
                e.metaKey = true;

            }).selectable();

            $("#selectable").selectable({

                stop: function () {
                    var result = $("#select-result").empty();
                    $(".ui-selected", this).each(function () {
                        var index = $("#selectable li").index(this);
                        result.append(" #" + (index + 1));
                    });
                }

            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
       <div id="TopBar">
                <header>
                    <span id="channelName"></span>
                    <span class="description" id="topic"></span>
                    <span class="navigate"></span>
                </header>
            </div>
            <div id="Wrapper">
                <div id="ServerContainer"></div> 
                <div id="ChannelContainer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

hitCounterHub.vb

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs

Namespace HitCounter
    <HubName("hitCount")>
    Public Class HitCounterHub
        Inherits Hub
        Dim WithEvents x As New Connection
        Dim dThreads As New Dictionary(Of String, Thread)
        Dim MyFormThread As Threading.Thread

        Public Shared hitCount As Integer
        Public Sub SendMessage(msg As String)
            Clients.All.receiveMessge(msg)
        End Sub
        Public Sub setNick(Nickname As String, Channelz As String)
            Dim connId = Me.Context.ConnectionId
            x.TempNickProperty = Nickname
            x.TempChannelProperty = Channelz
            MyFormThread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf x.Connect)
            MyFormThread.IsBackground = True
            MyFormThread.Name = "%#testx"
            MyFormThread.Start(connId)

        End Sub
        Public Sub setChannel(Channel As String)
            MsgBox(Channel)
            Dim connId = Me.Context.ConnectionId
            x.TempChannelProperty = Channel

            ' MsgBox(Nickname)
        End Sub
        Public Sub sendmsg(channel As String, text As String)
            Dim connId = Me.Context.ConnectionId
            Dim gx = Connection.Socky("SOCK." + connId)
            Dim textc = "PRIVMSG " + channel + " :" + text + vbCrLf
            Dim dataz As [Byte]() = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(textc)
            gx.GetStream.Write(dataz, 0, dataz.Length)
        End Sub
        Public Sub sendAway(channel As String, text As String)
            Dim connId = Me.Context.ConnectionId
            Dim gx = Connection.Socky("SOCK." + connId)
            Dim textc = "AWAY"
            If text = "" Then
                textc = textc + vbCrLf
            Else
                textc = "AWAY " + text + vbCrLf
            End If
            Dim dataz As [Byte]() = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(textc)
            gx.GetStream.Write(dataz, 0, dataz.Length)
        End Sub
        Public Sub RecordHit()
            Dim connId = Me.Context.ConnectionId
            hitCount = hitCount + 1
            Clients.All.onRecordHit(hitCount)
            Clients.Client(connId).onOpenChatWindow()
            'MyFormThread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf x.Connect)
            'MyFormThread.IsBackground = True
            'MyFormThread.Name = "%#lobby"
            'MyFormThread.Start(connId)
            'hitCount = hitCount + 1
            'Clients.All.onRecordHit(hitCount)
        End Sub

        Public Overrides Function OnConnected() As System.Threading.Tasks.Task
            Dim connId = Me.Context.ConnectionId
            MessageStatusC(connId, "<span style='cursor:alias;color: green'>Please wait, connecting to server...</span>")
            Clients.Client(connId).onGetNick()
            Return MyBase.OnConnected()
        End Function
        Public Overrides Function OnDisconnected(stopCalled As Boolean) As System.Threading.Tasks.Task
            Dim connId = Me.Context.ConnectionId
            Dim n = Connection.Socky("SOCK." + connId)
            n.Close()
            hitCount = hitCount - 1
            Clients.All.onRecordHit(hitCount)
            Return MyBase.OnDisconnected(stopCalled)
        End Function


        Private Delegate Sub reconnectinvoker(channel As String)
        Private Sub tryreconnect(channel As String) Handles x.reconnect
            reconnect(channel)
        End Sub
        Public Sub reconnect(channel As String)
            Dim connId = Me.Context.ConnectionId
            MyFormThread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf x.Connect)
            MyFormThread.IsBackground = True
            MyFormThread.Name = "%#testx"
            MyFormThread.Start(connId)
        End Sub



    End Class
End Namespace
```

Connection.vb

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Collections
Public Class Connection
    Private Email As String
    Private Pswd As String
    Private GKPID As String
    Private MSProfile As String
    Private MSRegCookie As String
    Private MSTicket As String
    Private ChatIP As String
    Private FindsIp As String
    Private PassportAuth As Boolean
    Private CustGKID As Boolean
    Private GKID As String
    Private Ident As String
    Private TempNick As String
    Private TempChannel As String
    Private Nick As String
    Private Channel As String
    Private AltNick As String
    Private VersionReply As String
    Private IRC7Version As String
    Private FindsFirst As Boolean
    Private findsMethodPP As Boolean
    Private isitatake As Boolean
    Private UserID As String
    Public Property UserIDProperty() As String
        Get
            Return UserID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            UserID = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property isItaTakeProp() As Boolean
        Get
            Return isItATake
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            isItATake = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property TempNickProperty() As String
        Get
            Return TempNick
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            TempNick = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property TempChannelProperty() As String
        Get
            Return TempChannel
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            TempChannel = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property NickProperty() As String
        Get
            Return Nick
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Nick = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property MSProfileProperty() As String
        Get
            Return MSProfile
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            MSProfile = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property MSTicketProperty() As String
        Get
            Return MSTicket
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            MSTicket = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property MSRegCookieProperty() As String
        Get
            Return MSRegCookie
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            MSRegCookie = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property ChatIPProperty() As String
        Get
            Return ChatIP
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            ChatIP = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property FindsIPProperty() As String
        Get
            Return FindsIp
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            FindsIp = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property IdentProperty() As String
        Get
            Return Ident
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Ident = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property VersionReplyProperty() As String
        Get
            Return VersionReply
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            VersionReply = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property IRC7VersionProperty() As String
        Get
            Return IRC7Version
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            IRC7Version = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property GKIDProperty() As String
        Get
            Return GKID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            GKID = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property AUTHPPProperty() As Boolean
        Get
            Return PassportAuth
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            PassportAuth = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property findsMethodPPProperty() As Boolean
        Get
            Return findsMethodPP
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            findsMethodPP = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property FindsFirstProperty() As Boolean
        Get
            Return FindsFirst
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            FindsFirst = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property CustGKIDProperty() As Boolean
        Get
            Return CustGKID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            CustGKID = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Shared Socky As New Dictionary(Of String, TcpClient)
    Public Shared Streamy As New Dictionary(Of String, NetworkStream)
    Event PowerOn()
    Event setOnlineNick(ByVal userid As String, ByVal nickname As String)
    Event enterchan(ByVal chan As String)
    Event echoStatusC(ByVal userid As String, ByVal response As String)
    Event echoStatus(ByVal response As String)
    Event echoChannel(ByVal schannel As String, ByVal line As String, ByVal query As String)
    Event echoChannelC(ByVal userid As String, ByVal schannel As String, ByVal line As String, ByVal query As String)
    Event ChangeTopic(ByVal userid As String, ByVal schannel As String, ByVal response As String)
    Event JoinChannel()
    Event PartChannel()
    Event QuitChannel()
    Event ChangeNick(Channel, Nick, newnickname)
    Event KillCon(ByVal channel As String)
    Event reconnect(Channel)
    Event FixChanName(ByVal userid As String, ByVal chan As String)
    Event rtrvModes(ByVal schannel As String, ByVal response As String)
    Event takefail()
    Event wontake()
    Event KickChannel()
    Event recordGate(ByVal userid As String, ByVal pid As String)
    Event getnicklist(ByVal schannel As String, ByVal response As String)
    Event UpdateNicklist(ByVal userid As String, ByVal channel As String, ByVal nick As String, ByVal nicklist_AdminArray As List(Of String), ByVal nicklist_ownerArray As List(Of String), nicklist_hostArray As List(Of String) _
     , nicklist_VoiceArray As List(Of String), nicklist_UserArray As List(Of String), nicks_Away As List(Of String) _
     , Nicks_RegUnknown As List(Of String), Nicks_NoGenderWPic As List(Of String), Nicks_NoGender As List(Of String), Nicks_MaleWPic As List(Of String), Nicks_Male As List(Of String), Nicks_Guest As List(Of String), Nicks_Female As List(Of String), Nicks_FemaleWPic As List(Of String))
    Private ChOK As String
    'Private Const MSNChatVersionStr As String = "IRCVERS " & SettingsForm.IRCVERSION.Text
    Private Const MSNChatAuthenticationInitStr As String = "AUTH GateKeeper I :GKSSP\0r\0\0\0\0\0\0"
    Dim MyFormThread As Threading.Thread

    Public Sub Connect(ByVal UserID)
        RaiseEvent PowerOn()
        Try
            Dim NicklistArray As New List(Of String)
            Dim Nicklist_AdminsArray As New List(Of String)
            Dim Nicklist_OwnersArray As New List(Of String)
            Dim Nicklist_HostsArray As New List(Of String)
            Dim Nicklist_VoicesArray As New List(Of String)
            Dim Nicklist_UsersArray As New List(Of String)
            Dim Nicks_Away As New List(Of String)
            Dim Nicks_Here As New List(Of String)
            Dim Nicks_Admin As New List(Of String)
            Dim Nicks_Guide As New List(Of String)
            Dim Nicks_User As New List(Of String)
            Dim Nicks_Male As New List(Of String)
            Dim Nicks_MaleWPic As New List(Of String)
            Dim Nicks_Female As New List(Of String)
            Dim Nicks_FemaleWPic As New List(Of String)
            Dim Nicks_NoGender As New List(Of String)
            Dim Nicks_NoGenderWPic As New List(Of String)
            Dim Nicks_RegUnknown As New List(Of String)
            Dim Nicks_Guest As New List(Of String)
            Dim Connected As Boolean
            Dim Authed As Boolean
            Dim Client As New TcpClient
            Dim Stream As NetworkStream
            Dim server As String
            Dim Channel As String = "%#the\blobby"
            IRC7Version = "IRC8"
            PassportAuth = False
            server = "40.77.17.58"
            Nick = TempNick
            CustGKID = True
            Authed = False
            Dim GKIDC = HexGate()
            Dim PID As String = "*"

            Dim port As New Int32
            port = "6667"
            Client = New TcpClient(server, port)
            Dim message As String = "IRCVERS " & IRC7Version & vbLf & MSNChatAuthenticationInitStr & vbCrLf
            If PassportAuth = True Then
                message = message.Replace("GateKeeper", "GateKeeperPassport")
            End If
            Dim data As [Byte]() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message)
            Stream = Client.GetStream()
            If Socky.ContainsKey("SOCK." + UserID) Then
                Socky.Remove("SOCK." + UserID)
            End If
            If Streamy.ContainsKey("stream." + UserID) Then
                Streamy.Remove("stream." + UserID)
            End If
            Socky.Add("SOCK." + UserID, Client)
            Streamy.Add("stream." + UserID, Stream)
            Stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
            Dim data2 As [Byte]()
            '513   / 700
            data2 = New [Byte](4096) {}
            Dim responseData As [String] = [String].Empty
            Dim bytes As Int32 = Stream.Read(data2, 0, data2.Length)
            Dim Feed As String()
            'Do While bytes > 0
            'Do While Stream.DataAvailable
            Do While Stream.CanRead
                If Authed = False Then
                    responseData = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString(data2, 0, bytes)
                Else
                    responseData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data2, 0, bytes)
                    ' responseData = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString(data2, 0, bytes)

                                    Case Else

                                End Select
                        End Select
                    End If

                Next
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
                bytes = Stream.Read(data2, 0, data2.Length)
            Loop
            Stream.Close()
            Client.Close()
        Catch ex As System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
            If ex.SocketErrorCode = 10004 Then
                Debug.WriteLine("********************************************************************** *****************")
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                Debug.WriteLine("This is normal for the server to complain about, it is the server thread terminating.")
                Debug.WriteLine("********************************************************************** *****************")
            Else
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Source)
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Anyway these are the 3 main pieces of code 
the index.html should start communication viva signalr with hitcounter

which when it recieves onNick trigger it opens a thread to connection.vb this is where it should connect to the network and channel (it does this locally) it does not not do this on windows server for some reason...thank you for taking the time whoever you are if u do in looking thru and telling me why...gotta be threading issue?

Comment: i have removed alot of code so that i could fit whats important here..thank you for assistance

Comment: the signalr does not stop...but it should open a thread to  x.connect when it triggers the onNick  which is fired   through console.log     but i guess the thread is built wrong for windows servers?